# RShiny 'sticky' footer

Tags: html, css, shiny

It is possible to have a footer which stays at the bottom, but never overlaps other elements.
The next code sample works partially. The footer is display at the bottom of the main content, but should be displayed at the bottom of the window (although the main content is not fully filled).

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Set the content area to fill the entire window
  tags$style(type = "text/css", ".container-fluid { height: 100%; }"),
  # Create a content area with a fixed footer
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 12,
           # This is the main content area
           h1("This is a rshiny app"),
           p("You can add your own widgets and elements here"),
           # Add some filler text to enable scrolling
           p(paste(rep("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", 50), collapse = "\n"))
    ),
    column(width = 12,
           # This is the footer area
           tags$footer(style = "position: sticky; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray;",
                       p("This is the footer", style = "text-align: center;")
           )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The `position: fixed` does set the footer at the bottom, but will overlap the main content if it is filled (which requires a vertical scrollbar):

```
tags$footer(style = "position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray;",
                           p("This is the footer", style = "text-align: center;")
)
```